# Get same results as spacy web dependency visualizer

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have the following sentence:

```
kimchi, fermented-vegetable foods produced in Korea
```

I passed this to the Spacy dependency visualizer (with "merge phrases" checked):
[image]
I'm really happy with this result and tried to "remake" this in Python:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('merge_noun_chunks'))
doc = nlp("kimchi, fermented-vegetable foods produced in Korea")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

This gives me:

```
kimchi, fermented-vegetable foods
produced
in
Korea
```

So here `kimchi,` is merged with `fermented-vegetable foods` whereas I want it to be exact the same as in the example. I checked the github  [`parse_deps`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/efec28ce70a0ff69471cc379867deebe7eb881e0/spacy/displacy/__init__.py) function and this also uses the `doc.noun_chunks` so I can't understand the origin of the discrepancy and how I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do noun-chunk merging in my scripts:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp('kimchi, fermented-vegetable foods produced in Korea') 
spans = spacy.util.filter_spans(doc.noun_chunks)
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    [retokenizer.merge(span, attrs={"tag": span.root.tag, "dep": span.root.dep})for span in spans]

for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

Output:

```
kimchi
,
fermented-vegetable foods
produced
in
Korea
```